# Retrieve strings delimited by comma ignoring leading and trailing spaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I try to create the regex pattern to retrieve strings that are delimited by commas but  also by commas preceeded or followed by spaces.
Another requirment of the project is that the retrieved strings cannot have trailing and leading spaces.

This must work with php preg_match_all function.

**example 1:**
Testing string is:

```
'    Monday,Tuesday, Wednesday ,Hello World ,   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  , ,  a b c d e   '
```

Expected result are retrieved strings:

```
'Monday'
'Tuesday'
'Wednesday'
'Hello World'
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
'a b c d e'
```

**example 2:**
Testing string is:

```
'Monday, Tuesday'
```

Expected result are retrieved strings:

```
'Monday'
'Tuesday'
```

I tried to achieve it by using positive lookahead and positive lookbehind like this

```
(?<=[\s,]).*?(?=[\s,])
```

but it did not accept  spaces in strings and ignored strings at the edge of the testing string unless they had trailing spaces when at the end or leading spaces when at the beginning of the testing string.

Thank you

Comment: Better to use `trim` and `explode` instead of `regex` it creates a overhead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
(\b[^,]+\b)
```

See [RegEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lZ7qC4/1)

**Disclaimer:** This works if your string does not start/end with any special characters.

Comment: If a value does not start with a word character (like `<Monday>,+Tuesday,...`), [this `(\b[^,]+\b)` will not work as expected](https://regex101.com/r/lZ7qC4/2).

Comment: Yes.. i had that in mind.. but if there are no such strings.. it is the simplest possible.. Again, it depends on what the OP wants :)

Comment: This is more of a hack solution, only suitable with specific input. Please add a disclaimer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew added :)

Comment: Thank you @karthik manchala for clever solution. I probably will use yours. I need that for doing deserialisation of strings in router. Similar to MVC design pattern router. So I am going to use typical worlds in the strings as you guess.

Answer (score 2):

> This must work with php `preg_match_all` function.

If you do not want to use `explode`, you can use a rather complicated regex like

```
'~(?:^|,)\s*\K(?=[^,]*[^\s,])[^,]+?(?=\s*(?:,|$))~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lR7sR9/2)

Breakdown:

- `(?:^|,)` - matches the start of the string or `,`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\K` - omitting the currently matched symbols from the match value
- `(?=[^,]*[^\s,])` - require that the value is not whitespace only before the next `,`
- `[^,]+?` - matches one or more characters other than `,` as few as possible to accommodate for the following spaces (if any)
- `(?=\s*(?:,|$))` - the lookahead making sure there are zero or more whitespaces followed with `,` or end of string.

Comment: This is a generic solution for the current requirements.

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor Stribiżew for the illuminating and enlightening solution. Both answers yours and karthik manchala 's are usefull for me. In fact I did not need results of the strings with special characters but did not tell this.